# Unable to seek in MP3 encoded files

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, gstreamer

When I try to play any MP3 encoded song in Rhythmbox, the seek bar is disabled. Upon trying to play the same files in Totem, the same problem appears again.

I think that the problem started after following [option C in this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1117283), and then undoing it.

I've tried reinstalling `gstreamer0.1-plugin-ugly`, `gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg` and `gstreamer0.1-fluendo-mp3`, which are the packages I think Rhythmbox is asking for upon playing a MP3 encoded file.

Running Ubuntu 10.04, recently updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-ffmpeg` package allows playback of mp3s, but not seeking.  It's possible that if you have both `-plugins-ugly` and `-ffmpeg` installed, Rhythmbox (or any other gstreamer-based media player) will choose to use `-ffmpeg` istead of the `ugly` plugin, and you will not be able to seek.

`gstreamer0.1-plugin-ugly` should cover all of your mp3 needs, so you can safely uninstall the `gstreamer0.1-ffmpeg` package.

For more background on the issue, see [a similar bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=609434) reported against Banshee, and [the much older gstreamer bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162833) it was eventually closed as a duplicate of.  Also note that an mp3 parser is now included in the `-good` gstreamer plugin, so this issue should not affect newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Removed the package, did work in Totem but not Rhythmbox. Cleaned the library, restarted Rhythmbox and now it works fine! Thank you!